Can a data type of Date display as DD-MON-YYYY without having to change it to a Character data type?
When I view a data frame's column that is of type "Date", it displays as YYYY-MM-DD.
Is there a way to have data frames' date columns display as DD-MON-YYYY while still being of data type Date?

Sorry, no.  In R date objects are displayed in the ISO notation, YYYY-MM-DD.

while still being of data type Date No, ISO 8601 standard is the date format that the underlying code for class date uses. You can modify as.Date to print a different character format per default in your session (not recommended though), but not change the class definition.

yes of course format.data.frame(data.frame(x = Sys.Date(), y = 1, z = factor(1)), format = '%d-%b-%Y')

@rawr, thanks for your reply; however, when I run your example code the date (x) is of type character instead of as type date.

no the date prints as a character as dates always do. the class in the data frame is a date, but formatting or printing shows as character, so you can display the date in the format you like as a character but the class is still a date which is exactly how your question is worded

Yes you can! You can use the package Lubridate in R. (https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) to manipulate date formats while keeping it as a date. You can tell it what format you want it in (ymd, dmy, ect).

thanks for your reply. Can you please provide an example?
